# fast way to randomly pick entries with numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have 2D dataset `values.shape = (NxN)` and have 3 criteria. I want to make an image for those criteria with a color code. So I end up having a NxNx4 array `mask` which holds for every pixel boolean values for `(background, color 1, color2, color 3)`.

- If none of the criteria is fulfilled for a pixel, I set it to `[T, F, F, F]`, i.e. background.
- If any of the criteria are fulfilled (e.g. `[F, T, F, T]`), then the background is automatically `False` and then I want to randomly assign one of the according colors, so here `color1` or `color3`. If just one criterium is `True`, that's the one that gets picked.

In other words: If a pixel fulfills one criterion, it gets the according color. If it matches several criteria, one is randomly picked.

Right now, I do

```py
# assign a probability
p = mask/mask.sum(-1)[:, :, None]

# the indices of the colors
lst = np.arange(len(colors))

for i in range(mask.shape[0]):
    for j in range(mask.shape[1]):
        # randomly pick a color index where the mask is true
        idx = np.random.choice(lst, p=p[i,j])
        # assign that color to the pixel
        img[i,j,:] = colors[idx, :]
```

I can do everything up to that point fast with `numpy` expressions, but I cannot do this assignment without a double loop. Is there any way to avoid the double loop with some `numpy`-magic?

Comment: It seems there is a fight between the upvoters and downvoters on this question. Generally, the most famous reason for people to downvote is the lack of search (typically if there are similar past question already talking about this). There is a `size` parameter to `np.random.choice` that can be used to remove the loop but for a constant `p` argument which is not the case. Maybe the downvoters did not sufficiently look the details... Besides, a complete reproducible example tends to reduce downvotes ;) . How big is `len(colors)`? Only 4?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It may vary, but just a handful of colors. But the image may be 4000x4000 and several thousands of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to *efficiently* vectorize `np.random.choice` in this case using only Numpy (though there might be a faster way than 2 nested loops). The main issue with the provided implementation is that `np.random.choice` takes about several dozens of microseconds per call so the overall computation takes at least several minutes. This overhead comes from:

- Checks: for example Numpy check the probability of all p-items is equal to 1 (in `O(len(p))`);
- A slow Kahan summation in the Numpy implementation (that might be optimized).

A simple solution is to use **Numba** so to get ride of most of such overhead but Numba does not support the parameter `p`. It is not easy to make the computation efficient with large `p` arrays. One solution is to compute the **cumulative sum of `p`** and pick random value (between 0 and 1) so to select an item of `lst` with the probability in `p` based on a **binary search**. In fact, it is not even needed to select an item of `lst` since `lst[i] == i`. Here is a Numba-based implementation:

```py
# Faster equivalent of `np.random.choice(np.arange(len(p)), p=p)`
@nb.njit('(float64[::1],)')
def randomInt(p):
    assert p.size > 0
    if p.size == 1:
        return 0
    tmp = np.empty(p.size, np.float64)
    # Cumulative sum
    s = 0.0
    for i in range(p.size):
        s += p[i]
        tmp[i] = s
    # Renormalization (to increase the accuracy)
    rnd = np.random.rand() * s
    idx = np.searchsorted(tmp, rnd)
    return idx
```

This function is about **22 times faster** than the one of Numpy. However, it is a slighly less accurate if the standard deviation of the probability is huge (eg. most items set to 0.00001 and few to 0.2) or if the number of items is huge (eg. >10_000). That being said, a re-normalization should be enough to give very good results for thousands of items (and non-extreme standard deviations). Note that `p` is automatically re-normalized.

You can use this function in a pure-Python code but it is faster to also use Numba so to speed up the two nested loops (by putting the code in a Numba function).

---

Further optimizations

On most processors, the speed of `randomInt` is limited by the **dependency chain** of the `+=` operations on floating-point numbers. Indeed, it takes about 4 cycles on Skylake-related processors, 3 on previous architecture and also 3 on AMD Zen-based processors. This means that for 1000 items, the cumulative sum needs to takes at least 4000 cycles on Skylake (ie. 1 µs on a 4 GHz processor). An optimization is to **break the dependency chain** by the computing the even/odd parts of the cumulative sum with more independent instructions so the processor can better **overlap the latency**.

Another optimization is to parallelize the nested loops in Numba using `prange` and the decorator argument `parallel=True`. That being said, the scalability can be impacted by a contention of the allocator due to the many `np.empty` calls. This issue can be fixed by pre-allocating `tmp` in the outer loop and using `prange` only for this loop. The parameter of `randomInt` need to change so to include the temporary `tmp` array in parameter.

Here is an optimized Numba function (untested):

```py
@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1])')
def randomIntOpt(p, tmp):
    assert p.size > 0
    assert tmp.size == p.size
    if p.size == 1:
        return 0
    s1, s2 = p[0], p[1]
    tmp[0], tmp[1] = s1, s1 + s2
    # Optimized cumulative sum
    # (unrolled so to break the dependency chain)
    i1 = 2
    i2 = 3
    iMax = p.size
    while i2 < iMax:
        s1 += p[i1]
        tmp[i1] = s1 + s2
        s2 += p[i2]
        tmp[i2] = s1 + s2
        i1 += 2
        i2 += 2
    # Remainder
    if p.size % 2 == 1:
        s1 += p[i1]
        tmp[i1] = s1 + s2
    s = s1 + s2
    # Renormalization (to increase the accuracy)
    rnd = np.random.rand() * s
    idx = np.searchsorted(tmp, rnd)
    return idx
```

This function is about 32 times faster in sequential on my machine when called from CPython. When called from Numba, it is about **40 times faster**. Using multiple threads should make the speed up far better (>100 on mainstream PC processors). This should be enough for the computation to last few seconds. I expect the final computation to be clearly **memory-bound** due to the **huge size of `p`** (typically >200 GiB). Consider reducing its size for better performance (it does not seems reasonable to keep a >10 KiB array per pixel).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Very helpful already! I will just wait a bit in case a numpy-based answer shows up, but otherwise will accept this answer. Just to clarify:  `i` and `j` would go to 2000, but the number of colors would be small (typically 4 +/- 2), so the `p` array would  not be that large (still several 100 MB) as only one image is processed at a time.

Comment: Ha ok. I misunderstood this point. For a very small number of color like this, Numba function are even faster (56x for 6 colors on my machine in sequential from a pure-Python code and much faster from a Numba code). Note that the dependency chain optimization is not needed and can actually be counter-productive in this case. Other optimizations still applies.